# PHP writing 800 records to file(.txt) from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access records from database more than 8000 with 30 columns and write to text file separated by tab.
My php code is :

```
 $fp1 = fopen( 'obspg.txt', 'w' );
  fwrite( $fp1,"RETSKU\tProduct Title\tDetailed Description\tProduct Condition\tSelling Price\tAvailability\tProduct URL\tImage URL\tManufacturer Part Number\tManufacturer Name\tCategorization\tGender\tsize\tColor\n");
  //retrive records from database and write to file
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` ");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     fwrite($fp1,$row[`id`]."\t".$row[`title`]."\t".  $row[`description`]."\t".$row[`condition`]."\t". $row[`price`]."\t".$row[`availability`]."\t".$row[`link`]."\t". $row[`image_link`]."\t".$row[`mpn`]."\t".$row[`brand`]."\t".$row[`google_product_category`]."\t".$row[`Gender`]."\t".$row[`size`]."\t".$row[`Color`]."\n");
  } 
  fclose( $fp1 );
```

But it taking too long time to execute.How I can improve performance of code? I can not utilize more than 25% usage on my server.

Comment: instead of writing 800 times into file, write only 1. loop through your data, construct a single variable that holds everything, write that into your file.

Comment: @andrew You may easily run into memory constraints when doing so. Streaming into a file shouldn't be *that* terrifically inefficient. The file is kept open anyway and the same amount of data needs to be written in the end.

Answer (score 2):

construct the data u want to write in a variable and just do one write to file. its much more efficient.

```
$fp1 = fopen( 'obspg.txt', 'w' );

$outPut = "RETSKU\tProduct Title\tDetailed Description\tProduct Condition\tSelling Price\tAvailability\tProduct URL\tImage URL\tManufacturer Part Number\tManufacturer Name\tCategorization\tGender\tsize\tColor\n";

//retrive records from database and write to file
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $outPut .= $row[`id`]."\t".$row[`title`]."\t".  $row[`description`]."\t".$row[`condition`]."\t". $row[`price`]."\t".$row[`availability`]."\t".$row[`link`]."\t". $row[`image_link`]."\t".$row[`mpn`]."\t".$row[`brand`]."\t".$row[`google_product_category`]."\t".$row[`Gender`]."\t".$row[`size`]."\t".$row[`Color`]."\n";
} 

fwrite( $fp1,$outPut);
fclose( $fp1 );
```

Comment: Its not working. Is their any problem with my data some fields may be empty

Comment: Are u able to see any error messages? what is the exact issue?

Comment: $row[`price`] is decimal

Comment: I don't understand why $row[price] being decimal can be an issue in this case. I am guessing you are getting a response with no output. if so then memory is being exceeded, you can set it to write to file after every 500 rows, it should be easy to do.