# Php Select rows through html form, and write them to txt file

Tags: php, html, database, forms, fwrite

I have a database of my products inventory, with each products amount that is in stock and our prices for them.  I'm trying to make it so that when I type for example `12345` part # for it to search `$POST_partnumber` in table `inventory`. And take part number + our price of this item and write in a txt file for every part number I type in and hit enter.

```
partnumber ourprice
partnumber ourprice
partnumber ourprice
partnumber ourprice
```

I started getting the code and there is a few extra feature I will add on my own, but can't get it to search for user imput and put colum `our price` and `part number` into a txt file. 
Thanks

This is what I found:

```
$fp1 = fopen( 'obspg.txt', 'w' );

$outPut = "RETSKU\tProduct Title\tDetailed Description\tProduct Condition\tSelling Price\tAvailability\tProduct URL\tImage URL\tManufacturer Part Number\tManufacturer Name\tCategorization\tGender\tsize\tColor\n";

//retrive records from database and write to file
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$outPut .= $row[`id`]."\t".$row[`title`]."\t".  $row[`description`]."\t".$row[`condition`]."\t". $row[`price`]."\t".$row[`availability`]."\t".$row[`link`]."\t". $row[`image_link`]."\t".$row[`mpn`]."\t".$row[`brand`]."\t".$row[`google_product_category`]."\t".$row[`Gender`]."\t".$row[`size`]."\t".$row[`Color`]."\n";
} 

fwrite( $fp1,$outPut); 
fclose( $fp1 );
```

[Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902272/php-writing-800-records-to-file-txt-from-database)

Comment: This `$POST_partnumber` am raising a brow to that. Plus, you're using ticks `\`` instead of regular quotes `'` in your arrays. Error reporting would have signaled that.

Comment: You copied bad code and making the same mistake as that link you provided us with.

Comment: anyway, you've been given an answer below. Ask them. The solution is basically in my comment above really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do something like this. Using `file_put_contents()` & `file_get_contents()`

You just need to set some things

1. Change path test.php to your filename
2. Connection data $host, $user, $pass, $dbdb
3. Table & field names

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- path to current page -->
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">
Partnumber: <input type="text" name="part"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html> 

<?php

//connection data
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$host = "";
$dbdb = "";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
    trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['part'])){

    //retrive records from database and write to file
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `partnumber` = '".$_POST['part']."'");

    //count rows, number > 0 then partnumber exists
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            //check if part is in stock, when > 0 its in stock
            if ($row['stock'] > 0) { 

                echo "You already have " . $row['stock'] . " of part " . $row['partNumber'] . "in stock."; 

            } else { 

                echo "<br>Added partnumber: ". $_POST['part'] . "<br><br>";

                $output = $row['partNumber']." ". $row['promoCode'] . PHP_EOL;

                $file = 'test.txt';

                //check file existence
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    $current = file_get_contents($file);
                } else{
                    $current = null;
                }

                $current .= $output;

                echo nl2br($current);

                file_put_contents($file, $current);
            }
        }

    }else{
            echo "<br>Partnumber doesn't exist";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: This works good thanks, just one quick question how could I add something that would tell me not to add this part because its in stock?  Like `if ($row['stock'] > 0) {
    echo "You already have $row['stock'] of part $row['partNumber'] in stock.";
} else { !!!Put the rest of the action code here?!!! }`     Thanks.

Comment: @user3263981 I edited my answer. But I think you should have been able to do this yourself. Its just logic to find where to put it. and your code was almost  correct. Only the variables in your echo needed to be surrounded by  `". $row['stock'] ."`

Comment: Thanks so much.  You don't know how much you helped me :)  and sorry for asking simple stuff I do more HTML and CSS and only started getting into PHP a bit.  And I Included my own code in that comment to show you that I'm not making you do it for me just need a bit of help.  Thanks again. @PHpeter You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<form action="yourFile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="PartNumber" id="PartNumber">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['PartNumber'])){
    $fp1 = fopen( 'obspg.txt', 'w' );

    $outPut = "";

    //retrive records from database and write to file
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT PartNumber, Price FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE PartNumber = '".$_POST['PartNumber']."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $outPut .= $row['PartNumber']."\t".$row['Price']."\t\n";
    } 

    fwrite( $fp1,$outPut); 
    fclose( $fp1 );

}
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

You're using ticks in the arrays, such as:

```
$row[`id`]
```

where they should be regular quotes `$row['id']`, which would have thrown an error.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

- All of those arrays need to be changed to regular quotes.
- [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902272/php-writing-800-records-to-file-txt-from-database) to the post you included in your question, also contains ticks; it's incorrect.

Comment: double check that. it's also going to fail

Comment: why will it fail? read my comment to the OP. Then you have `name="partNumber"` and `$_POST['PartNumber']`. Remember, variables are case-sensitive in PHP, as it is in any other programming language. Try that code out with error reporting set and to display http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: True, yea I'm pretty careless with my syntax.  Dunno what id do without my code linters

Comment: You're welcome. I saw the edit, but re-read my comment above and compare letter-case.

Comment: Thank you!  Yea, using the isset() and !empty() is definitely better